# Represent a Guid as a set of integers

Tags: c#, algorithm, guid

If I want to represent a guid as a set of integers how would I handle the conversion? I'm thinking along the lines of getting the byte array representation of the guid and breaking it up into the fewest possible 32 bit integers that can be converted back into the original guid. Code examples preferred...

Also, what will the length of the resulting integer array be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow I had much more fun doing it this way:

```
byte[] bytes = guid.ToByteArray();
int[] ints = new int[bytes.Length / sizeof(int)];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) {
    ints[i / sizeof(int)] = ints[i / sizeof(int)] | (bytes[i] << 8 * ((sizeof(int) - 1) - (i % sizeof(int))));
}
```

and converting back:

```
byte[] bytesAgain = new byte[ints.Length * sizeof(int)];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) {
    bytesAgain[i] = (byte)((ints[i / sizeof(int)] & (byte.MaxValue << 8 * ((sizeof(int) - 1) - (i % sizeof(int))))) >> 8 * ((sizeof(int) - 1) - (i % sizeof(int))));
}
Guid guid2 = new Guid(bytesAgain);
```

Answer (score 6):

As a GUID is just 16 bytes, you can convert it to four integers:

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

byte[] bytes = id.ToByteArray();
int[] ints = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   ints[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, i * 4);
}
```

Converting back is just getting the integers as byte arrays and put together:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(ints[i]), 0, bytes, i * 4, 4);
}
Guid id = new Guid(bytes);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: this achieves the result but uses BitConverter which has the problem with Endianness

Comment: @SuryaPratap: Then you have to clarify why you think that is a problem.

Comment: well if the input comes from across the machine boundary, how do you know the byte order

Answer (score 5):

```
  System.Guid guid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    byte[] guidArray = guid.ToByteArray();

    // condition
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(guidArray.Length % sizeof(int) == 0);

    int[] intArray = new int[guidArray.Length / sizeof(int)];

    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(guidArray, 0, intArray, 0, guidArray.Length);


    byte[] guidOutArray = new byte[guidArray.Length];

    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(intArray, 0, guidOutArray, 0, guidOutArray.Length);

    System.Guid guidOut = new System.Guid(guidOutArray);

    // check
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(guidOut == guid);
```

Answer (score 2):

Will the build-in Guid structure not suffice?

Constructor:

```
public Guid(
    byte[] b
)
```

And

```
public byte[] ToByteArray()
```

Which, returns a 16-element byte array that contains the value of this instance.

Packing the bytes into integers and visa versa should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

A Guid is typically just a 128-bit number.

-- Edit

So in C#, you can get the 16 bytes via

```
byte[] b = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
```

Comment: does this mean it can be represented by 4 integers eg byte[0-3] ... byte [12-15]?

Comment: How do we convert back a byte array to 4 integers ?