# GUID type in database

Tags: database, database-design

`GUID` is not an official data type in database. In our existing SQL Server design, the `Uniqueidentifier` type is used for `GUID` value. Now we are switching to Sybase database. Should we use `varchar(36)` to replace that `Uniqueidentifier` type?

I am still confused by `GUID`. I was told `GUID` is 16 bytes long but its character string is 36 characters in length. I must missed something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A GUID is actually an integer type - it's a 128 bit integer (16 bytes).

It's often represented as a string of 36 characters - but the actual value is a 128bit integer value.

Comment: ok, so we cannot use varchar(36) to take the GUID value because it is an integer type. but how to represent a 16 types integer type?

Comment: +1. The number of characters can vary with representation, but always consists of 32 hexadecimal digits, but can sometimes include curly braces and hyphens.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no 16byte integer type.  You can use 2 BIGINT columns (8 bytes each), or a BINARY(16) to hold the data...

Comment: @Adam: Very true - the "36 character" is a common representation, adding {} and 2 dashes.

Answer (score 5):

The reason that it's 36 characters is that a Guid is typically displayed as:

```
########-####-####-####-############

# = 1 hex character (0-9, A-F)
32 hex chars and 4 hyphens
```

A quick Google search found this Sybase site for [newid](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks177.htm) that may help you out.

Comment: +1. Judging by that page, it seems that Sybase uses varchar(32) to store its Guid values.

Answer (score 2):

There is type `uniqueidentifier`.
`varchar(36)` should be equivalent in other databases.

To convert a `uniqueidentifier` value to a `char` data type:

```
DECLARE @myid uniqueidentifier
SET @myid = NEWID()
SELECT CONVERT(char(255), @myid) AS 'char'
GO
```

[uniqueidentifier (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx)

Comment: yes, that is for SQL server what we have now. we want to change to Sybase.

Comment: Then you need to convert before importing.

Answer (score 2):

Since an integer is 32 bits and a Guid is 128 bits, you could convert your Guid to four 32 bit integers (or two 64 bit integers). See here: [Represent a Guid as a set of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353555/represent-a-guid-as-a-set-of-integers)

But it would probably be easier to keep it in the database as a string (or binary) if you don't have a native Guid type. Unfortunately, you won't have the ability to generate them on the database side like in SQL Server, so its use as a primary key would be limited.