# Workflow's Id from type Guid

Tags: database, workflow

I want to save in my DB the id of the current workflow. but its id from type Guid (which i don't know before) but the column in DB can't recognize this type. 
I thought about downcasting it to int, but when I want to retrieve it may its not safe to downcast it to Guid type.
Any idea?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should use varchar(36) and store it as string only.

this could help you

[GUID type in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547947/guid-type-in-database)